# COVID and comorbidity

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Suppose the probability to die if you get the Covid disease is $1\%$ (just an assumption, it's not a real number) and $3\%$ of death are people who have a comorbidity $C$. So using conditional probability:

$P(\text{Death|get covid}) = 1\%$

$P(\text{have a comorbidity|death and get Covid}) = 3\%$

I want to know the $P(\text{death|get Covid, comorbidity C})$, I have an intuition I only need these information to solve this problem, but I couldn't do it using only what I have.

Comment: you don't have enough information to conclude...

Comment: @Surb What is missing? thank you

Comment: $P(death | comorbidity)$ isn't dependent on covid in any way. Perhaps you want $P(death | covid, comorbidity)$?

Comment: @cgss yes, I`ve already edited the question, thank you!

Comment: I suck at probability/ statistics, but this smells like Bayes’ Theorem because of the conditional stuff

Comment: Hi. Does anyone know a team that needs help with the software? I'd like to help